# Linking two (or more) UISegmented Controls

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to get the answer from my first segmented control to then automatically select the answer to the second (and more) segmented controls, if the selected answer is `No`.

So `Question1` segmented control (Yes, No, N/A), if `No` is selected, then make answer to `Question2` (and Q3,Q4 etc) segmented control to `N/A`.
I can get it to work on `Question1` alone, ie press `No` but changes to `N/A` on `Question1`, but I want it to leave `Question1` as `No`, but then change `Question2` etc to `N/A`.

I tried changing `sender` to `Question2`, but that doesn't work.

```
        @IBOutlet weak var Queston2: UISegmentedControl! //Will need to add same for Q3 etc

        @IBAction func Question1(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

            if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            //Do stuff
            }

            else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

                sender.selectedSegmentIndex = 2                  // Change button to 'N/A', works for this question, but i want it to change Question2, not Question1.

         @IBAction func Question2(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) { // generally repeats as Question1 above.
```

I've found a few similar answers, but they seem far more complicated than I think I need.

Comment: So - you have *n* number of `UISegmentedControl` objects, all with "Yes - No - N/A", and when No is selected on any one of them, all the others should be set to "N/A"? But if Yes or N/A is selected, do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically what you could do:

```
class ArrayOfSegsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var q1SegControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet var q2SegControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet var q3SegControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet var q4SegControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet var q5SegControl: UISegmentedControl!


    @IBAction func q1SegControlChangeed(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            // do stuff
        } else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            // set all others to "N/A"
            [q2SegControl, q3SegControl, q4SegControl, q5SegControl].forEach {
                $0.selectedSegmentIndex = 2
            }
        } else {
            // do stuff
        }

    }

}
```

In the `== 1` block, you create an array of the other segmented controls and loop through, saying "for each control, set the selected segment index to 2."

Side notes: use

```
lowerCaseFirstChar
```

for variables and function names. Use

```
UpperCaseFirstChar
```

for classes / structs / enums / etc.

Comment: @ColinD - are you laying these all out in Storyboard? Or creating them via code? Either way, with that many, you'll likely be better off putting them in an array. You can then use `arrayOfControls.forEach`

Comment: I have set this out in the Storeyboard, now works fine.

Comment: @ColinD - if that answered your question, be sure to mark the answer as Accepted for the benefit of anyone else who comes across it.

Comment: Thanks, done now, I didn't know about that as it's my first question. Thanks.